# What does purple colour mean in GPU rendering profiling?

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop

In this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfDs2OWLQuk) you can see lags in the Easter egg in Android Lollipop on Nexus 5

[image: GPU profiling on Lollipop]

What does purple colour mean?

Comment: The colours are:

Blue: Indicating time spent creating drawing commands

Orange: Issuing the commands

Yellow: Waiting for the commands to complete. For more info look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854103/android-4-3-on-screen-gpu-profiling-long-gfx-waiting-time Also, please ignore my answer. I was completely wrong. I thought you meant talking about the blue!!

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the link, but there is nothing about purple there.

Comment: Sorry that I can't really help you, as I don't know either. It's an excellent question though! +1

Answer (score 3):

Purple is "prepare"

It has been added in Lollipop, so now we get:
draw (blue), prepare (purple), process (red), execute (yellow)

If you do `adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo`, the table for each app now has 4 columns (with prepare added between draw and process)

I have yet to find any documentation on this yet :)